# How to create full / advance text search in scylladb and cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, full-text-search, cassandra-3.0, scylla

I have installed the latest version of scylladb and cassandra in my centos os. i have tried allow filtering in select query but i don't need it, I want advance search or full text search in it, i have google it but couldn't find any solution, when i create indexes and try to run the select query it gives error **"server error: not implemented: indexes"**.
can any one help me please?

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndex.html

Comment: thanks for reply, unfortunately i have tried this before it gives the same error which i mentioned in question

Comment: Which cassandra version are you using ?

Comment: i am using Cassandra 3.0.8

Comment: SASI introduced in cassandra 3.4 https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/CHANGES.txt#L969

Comment: Actually i have installed the latest version of scylla where i am using cassandra, cassandra 3.0 is automatically installed with the latest version of scylla

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scylla is actively working to enable secondary indexes. Expecting to have a working solution with 2.2 release
http://www.scylladb.com/product/technology/scylla-roadmap/

To currently support a full text search with Scylla, an auxiliary solution such as Solr or Elasticsearch is needed, the following link explains how to combine a Scylla and Elasticsearch

http://www.scylladb.com/2017/08/03/data-analytics-elastic-scylla/

Answer (score 6):

If you are using cassandra version 3.4 or above then you can use [SSTable Attached Secondary Index (SASI)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndexConcept.html).

> Using CQL, SSTable attached secondary indexes (SASI) can be created on a non-collection column defined in a table. Secondary indexes are used to query a table that uses a column that is not normally queryable, such as a non primary key column. SASI implements three types of indexes, PREFIX, CONTAINS, and SPARSE.

Learn more on : https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndex.html

Or You could use [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co/). So when ever any searchable data created, updated or deleted you have index or delete the data from solr or elastic search.

Comment: i am unable to update cassandra  because i am using it with scylladb in centos 7
cassandra 3.0.8 has been installed with latest scylla

Comment: Then use solr or elastic search along with cassandra/scylladb

Comment: i can not use apache solr and elastic search because i am using datastax cassandra not apache cassandra

Comment: I am talking about using external solr/elasticsearch